# Only able to detect and track up to 4 images at a time with ARKit 3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

Using the code below I'm only able to detect and track up to 4 images at any one time when using ARKit.

```
ARImageTrackingConfiguration *configuration = [ARImageTrackingConfiguration new];  
configuration.trackingImages = [ARReferenceImage referenceImagesInGroupNamed:@"AR Resources" bundle:nil];  
configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 100;  
[self.sceneView.session runWithConfiguration:configuration];
```

Is anyone able to confirm what I'm seeing? I need to be able to track a larger number of images/markers and was excited when I saw this offered in the ARKit 3 announcement.

Would be great if someone is able to replicate this so I know I'm not imagining things ^^

I hope this isn't an Apple limitation, the 3DS could detect and track more than 4 images over 8 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the official answer in a comment made to ARImageTrackingConfiguration:

```
@discussion Image tracking provides 6 degrees of freedom tracking of known images. Four images may be tracked simultaneously.
```

EDIT: Found in ARConfiguration.h, line 336

Comment: Sorry, could you give a link to that comment?

Comment: It's not in any of the docs, but it *is* found in Apple's code:

Go to ARConfiguration.h, line 336

Answer (score 3):

**Updated**: July 18, 2022.

### ARKit 6.0+

Apple has promised that starting from ARKit 5.0 you'll be able to simultaneously track up to 100 images.

### ARKit 4.0 and earlier

In ARKit 4.0 you can simultaneously track up to 4 images. Not more than four.

Even though ARKit 3.0 official documentation says that `.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages` instance property could be equals to `100`, this hundred of images is just a total number of tracked images in a session. Apple software engineers limited image tracking feature to **four images at a time**. This makes sense because tracking more than four images at a time is very CPU- and GPU-expensive.

> Also, you can read about it **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59978435/can-i-track-more-than-4-images-at-a-time-with-arkit/59981180#59981180)**.

```objectivec
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    ARWorldTrackingConfiguration *config = [ARWorldTrackingConfiguration new];
    config.detectionImages = [ARReferenceImage referenceImagesInGroupNamed:@"Resources" bundle:nil];

    config.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 100;       // in ARKit 3.0
    // config.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 25;     // in ARKit 2.0

    [self.sceneView.session runWithConfiguration:config];
}
```

Comment: I've tried both and experience the same issue. The images are always in view of the camera and we have no interest in the planes of the world so ARImageTrackingConfiguration is ideal for us. The issue is ARKit only detects and tracks up to 4 images on screen at once (despite looking at a much larger group of markers). Are you able to track more than 4 images on screen at once?

Comment: What is Reference Image resolution?

Comment: of the captured stream? 1920x1440
EDIT: Reference image resolution is 800x800, physical size ~1 inch square