# ARKit removes a node when Reference Image disappeared

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I'm building AR Scanner application where users are able to scan different images and receive rewards for this.

When they point camera at some specific image - I place `SCNNode` on top of that image and after they remove camera from that image - `SCNNode` get's dismissed.

But when image disappears and camera stays at the same position `SCNNode` didn't get dismissed.

**How can I make it disappear together with Reference image disappearance?**

I have studied lot's of other answers here, on SO, but they didn't help me

Here's my code for adding and removing `SCNNode`'s:

```
extension ARScannerScreenViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { self.instructionLabel.isHidden = true }
    if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor {
        handleFoundImage(imageAnchor, node)
        imageAncors.append(imageAnchor)
        trackedImages.append(node)
    } else if let objectAnchor = anchor as? ARObjectAnchor {
        handleFoundObject(objectAnchor, node)
    }
}

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    guard let pointOfView = sceneView.pointOfView else { return }
    for (index, item) in trackedImages.enumerated() {
        if !(sceneView.isNode(item, insideFrustumOf: pointOfView)) {
            self.sceneView.session.remove(anchor: imageAncors[index])
        }
    }
}

private func handleFoundImage(_ imageAnchor: ARImageAnchor, _ node: SCNNode) {
    let name = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name!
    print("you found a \(name) image")

    let size = imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize
    if let imageNode = showImage(size: size) {
        node.addChildNode(imageNode)
        node.opacity = 1
    }
}

private func showImage(size: CGSize) -> SCNNode? {
    let image = UIImage(named: "InfoImage")
    let imageMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    imageMaterial.diffuse.contents = image

    let imagePlane = SCNPlane(width: size.width, height: size.height)
    imagePlane.materials = [imageMaterial]

    let imageNode = SCNNode(geometry: imagePlane)
    imageNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
    return imageNode
}

private func handleFoundObject(_ objectAnchor: ARObjectAnchor, _ node: SCNNode) {
    let name = objectAnchor.referenceObject.name!
    print("You found a \(name) object")
}
```

}

I also tried to make it work using `ARSession`, but I couldn't even get to prints:

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
    for anchor in anchors {
        for myAnchor in imageAncors {
            if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor, imageAnchor == myAnchor {
                if !imageAnchor.isTracked {
                    print("Not tracked")
                } else {
                    print("tracked")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you using for session configuratio ARImageTrackingConfiguration or ARWorldTrackingConfiguration? If you are using ARWorldTrackingConfiguration then switch to ARImageTrackingConfiguration and it will do the trick.

Comment: I'm using both of these methods, as I need not only discover images, but objects as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use **[ARWorldTrackingConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration)** instead of [ARImageTrackingConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arimagetrackingconfiguration). It's quite bad idea to use both configurations in app because each time you switch between them – tracking state is reset and you have to track from scratch.

Let's see what Apple documentation says about ARImageTrackingConfiguration:

> With `ARImageTrackingConfiguration`, ARKit establishes a 3D space **not by tracking the motion of the device relative to the world**, but solely by detecting and tracking the motion of known 2D images in view of the camera.

**The basic differences between these two configs are about how ARAnchors behave**:

- ***ARImageTrackingConfiguration*** allows you get `ARImageAnchors` only if your reference images is in a Camera View. So if you can't see a reference image – there's no ARImageAnchor, thus there's no a 3D model (it's resetting each time you cannot-see-it-and-then-see-it-again). You can simultaneously detect [up to 100 images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59978435/can-i-track-more-than-4-images-at-a-time-with-arkit/59981180#59981180).
- ***ARWorldTrackingConfiguration*** allows you track a surrounding environment in 6DoF and get `ARImageAnchor`, `ARObjectAnchor`, or `AREnvironmentProbeAnchor`. If you can't see a reference image – there's no ARImageAnchor, but when you see it again ARImageAnchor is still there. So there's no reset.

**Conclusion**:

**`ARWorldTrackingConfiguration`**'s cost of computation is much higher. However this configuration allows you perform not only image tracking but also hit-testing and ray-casting for detected planes, object detection, and a restoration of world maps.

Comment: Sorry for late reply but you answer did help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `nodeForAnchor` to load your nodes, so when the anchors disappear, the nodes will go as well.

Comment: But I'm already using `func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)`, or this is another method? Could you specify please?

Comment: yes, it does almost the same as the one you are using.