# How do I scan a QR Code using RealityKit?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I am building an iOS app using `RealityKit`. I would like to read a QR Code within `ARView` but cannot find any documentation/tutorials on it.

- `RealityKit`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit
- `ArView`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/arview

Any advice/guidance on doing this would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In RealityKit you can **RECOGNIZE** a QR code or brand-new AppClipCode using image recognition technique. For this create `AR Resources` directory in `Assets.xcassets` and place `JPEG` or `PNG` images with QR codes there. You can use up to 100 images per project. Then use `.image` init for your anchor entity.

```
let anchor = AnchorEntity(.image(group: "AR Resources", name: "qrCodeImage"))
anchor.addChild(modelEntity)
arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
```

Since ARKit and RealityKit have similar capabilities under the hood, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59978435/can-i-track-more-than-4-images-at-a-time-with-arkit) post for additional information.

But you can't **READ** any QR code (I mean extract an info contained in QR) using only RealityKit framework.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That makes a lot of sense. As a follow up question, if I have multiple objects that have the same exact appearance but want to differentiate them in RealityKit, how would you go about doing that? My idea was to use QR codes but it seems that will not work.

Comment: Hi @mtreiber13, please publish it as a new question (with a code you already wrote).